# Dreamweaver can load api request, but Google Chrome cannot

Tags: javascript, php, html, mod-rewrite, steam-web-api

So I'm trying to use the steam web api and create a simple page that displays the user's friend list. So far I managed to get an arraylist containing all the steam-64 ids of the user's friend list. However, the problem is I tested this on the **live view feature in Dreamweaver.**

When I load it into Google Chrome, nothing displays it returns this error in the console:

> Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest'. Failed to load http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetFriendList/v0001/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamid=76561197960435530&relationship=friend

However, when I test it using the live feature on Dreamweaver, I get this:

[image]

**The steam-id shown below the sign in button demonstrates that my code is working.**

I am currently using xampp (so apache) to run my php file. I have configured it in Dreamweaver properly and I've also enabled mod_rewrite and mod_proxy. However, the request cannot still be loaded when I display in Google Chrome.

If anyone can please help, it would be appreciated.

Comment: it is cross domain request, so the browser will apply [Same Origin Policy](https://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy)

Comment: So how do I fix that?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Comment: from the documentation it doesn't look like they are supporting either CORS or JSONP... so one solution is to make your webserver act like a proxy... ie you sent the ajax request to your server which will make a http request to the remote api and forward the returned data to the client browser

Comment: @ArunPJohny how woukd I be abke to do that? Sorry I am kind of new to web servers.and php.

Comment: @ArunPJohny can you join my chat please? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60287/cors-enable

Comment: @ArunPJohny okay but could you at least help me solve the CORS problem?